# HTML question: Moving one list item to another dynamically

Tags: html, frontend

I'd like to know if there are any tips and tricks or possible tutorials that could achieve the effect of transferring one list item on a page to from one ul to another.

Say you have two unordered list with button controls on each list item, and everytime you click on the button on each item, it moves it to the other list on the same page, in a dynamic, fancy way.

Many thanks, any help or leads would be appreciated!

Comment: A `<ul>` or would a [select list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) be better?

Answer (score 0):

See "6. Moving options from list A to list B" at http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JQuery UI library. They have MANY drag and drop kind of features. I'm sure you can find what you are looking for.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists